# How to access Controls in aspx page from CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

my aim is the following:

1. Put some ImageButtons on an aspx page (with masterpage)
2. Each ImageButton is actually a PlaceHolder, where I want to load an Image. I assume to have, at start, no ImageButton.ImageUrl.
3. When clicking on an ImageButton, I want the ImageButton to display an image (the final goal is to load it from local machine, but, for now I use a fixed image)

My idea is to change the ImageButton.imageUrl after a ImageButtonClick.

The Aspx page has an Asp:Panel with ID=FOGLIO, and contains an ImageButton with ID=HEADERLOGO.

I tried to google all related topics, but my code, actually refuses to work. Some basic mistake may be, because none of the controls in the page is retrieved, as evidenced by a Response.Write that I have put during a PostBack. I don't see anyway to do what I want. Does anybody have any hint?

Aspx markup and code behind follow.

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
        CodeBehind="Images.aspx.cs" Inherits="Monitas.Images" %>
          <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
            <style media="all">

             .Sheet {position: relative; left: 15%; top:15%; background: white; width: 800px; 
                        height: 900px; border:3px solid #000;}

             .HeaderLogo {position: relative; background: yellow; width:240px; height:100px; 
                        left: 500px; top: 1px;  border:1px solid #000;}

           </style>

         </asp:Content>

       <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

      <asp:Panel ID="FOGLIO" class="Sheet" runat="server">

          <asp:ImageButton class="HeaderLogo" ID="HEADERLOGO" alternateText="Header Logo" 
                  runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" OnClick="OnImageHeaderClick" />

      </asp:Panel>

     </asp:Content>
```

The code behind:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using static Monitas.GlobalVars;

    namespace Monitas
    {
      public partial class Images : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack) // in a PostBack, following the OnImageHeaderClick
        {
            Panel p = (Panel)FindControl("FOGLIO");
            Response.Write("<<" + p + ">>"); // <<<< always null
            if (p!=null)
            {
                ImageButton img = (ImageButton)FindControl("HEADERLOGO");
                Response.Write("<<" + img + ">>");
                if (img!=null)
                    img.ImageUrl=HeadImage;
            }
        }

    }

    protected void OnImageHeaderClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        HeadImage = Server.MapPath("../Monitas/Images/FooterLogo.png"); // use another image 
                after clicking on the previous
    }


    }
  }
```

Comment: Your code-behind should just be able to reference `HEADERLOGO.ImageUrl` directly, without needing the `FindControl` calls. If that doesn't work, the `sender` parameter in the `OnImageHeaderClick` event handler will be the `ImageButton` control.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. Actually, what you suggested was my first trial. So I did the following:  if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                HEADERLOGO.ImageUrl = HeadImage;
            } but ImageUrl, is not displayed. This was the real problem I have.

Comment: After your comment, I have discovered a strange behaviour. (1) The ImageButton.ImageUrl is actually not updated after the OnImageHeaderClick. (2) Only after a second OnImageHeaderClick, the ImageUrl  is assumed. In practice, what I want, that is to update the Image inside the ImageButton, is obtained only after a second click on it.

Comment: Hi. @RichardDeeming. I did as you did and it is true. I was trying this way to overcome another problem, that I posted now, in another thread. So, if you want to send your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Barring compiler errors, all controls with `runat="server"` and an `ID` attribute, and which aren't nested within a data-bound control, will be available as fields in the code-behind.

In this case, you should be able to reference `HEADERLOGO` directly from your code-behind, without having to resort to `FindControl`.

If all else fails, the `sender` parameter of the `OnImageHeaderClick` event handler will also be a reference to the image button.

It's also worth pointing out that you change the `HeadImage` property *after* setting the `ImageUrl` property. The update will not be visible until you click on the image button a second time.

And finally, `Server.MapPath` will return the physical path of the file on your server. That won't work as an image URL: the user browsing your site almost certainly won't have an image file in the same path on their computer; and even if they did, it's almost certainly not the same image as the one on your server; and even if it was, a website cannot reference images stored on the local filesystem.

```c#
protected void OnImageHeaderClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    HeadImage = "~/Monitas/Images/FooterLogo.png";
    
    // If you want the image URL to be updated immediately:
    HEADERLOGO.ImageUrl = HeadImage;
}
```

Comment: Ok@RichardDeeming. I understood. I have posted again my actual problem, to which you indirectly answered: i don't see the way not to be forced to click a second time. Things are clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it probably better to use a listview (my favorte), but say lets use a grid view.

We have this grid view with some columns, and a image button:

eg this:

```
    <div style="padding:30px;width:50%">

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Fighter" HeaderText="Fighter"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Engine" HeaderText="Engine"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Thrust" HeaderText="Thrust"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnImage" runat="server" Height="68px" Width="149px"
                            OnClientClick ="popimage(this);return false"
                            ImageUrl = '<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' /> 
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

Now our data is this:

[image]

And code to load is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Fighters", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And now we have this:

[image]

Now, I have jQuery, but we COULD add some code to click on a image, and dispay it say in a popup - much larger.

So on the image button, we have a click event. We stuff the given row click (url) in to a MUCH larger image control we have hidden on the page, and then call jQuery.UI "dialog' to display that image in a dialog.

So, lets add the click event - and WE CAN do this 100% client side!!

So, we add a div to hold the image, and this code:

```
                <div id="imagepop" style="display:none;text-align:center;height:80%">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
                    style="height:96%"/>
                </div>

            <script>
                function popimage(btn) {
                    FromImage = $(btn)
                    ToImage = $("#Image1")
                    ToImage.attr("src", FromImage.attr("src"))

                    pHeight = ($(window).height() * 0.96)
                    pWidth = ($(window).width() * 0.80)

                    myDialog = $("#imagepop");                    
                    myDialog.dialog({
                        title: "Fighter",
                        modal: true,
                        height: pHeight,
                        width: pWidth,
                        closeText: "",
                        show : "fade",
                        buttons: {

                            Ok: function () {
                                myDialog.dialog("close")
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            </script>
```

So, now I click on the image in the row, and we have this:

[image]

So, use a grid or listview - even a repeater. Place one image control, and repeat it for the many pictures you want to display.

Fyi: I assume both jquery and jquery.ui for the dialog pop up.

## Edit: click on image button - show image in button

So for image button click event, then this:

protected void OnImageHeaderClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

```
    HEADERLOGO.ImageUrl = 
       Server.MapPath("../Monitas/Images/FooterLogo.png"); // use another image 
}
```

Comment: Hi. @Albert D.Kallal. Great advices. My problem is slightly different, by your answer is very useful.

Comment: Well, one clicks on the image button, then for that button event code behind, just set ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "path to image in code. And for one button click this should work. SEE MY NEW EDIT that shows how to set the image for the image button click.

Comment: OK. @Albert D.Kallal. The original idea was to click on the imagebutton, display an OpenFileDialog, choose a file, upload it and subsititute the ImageUrl on the clicked ImageButton. This should be done for five ImageButtons. The mechanism in this post was a first step, because I wanted to see whether the image changed or not, using a fixed image already inside the site. What you say in this comment was my first trial and didn't work, Moreover in previous answer Richard Deeming pointed out that the ServerMapPath cannot be used to set up the ImageUrl.  Thanks a lot for your contribute.

Comment: Ok, but say I dropped in a up-load file - one that lets me up-load 1 , or 8 files - don't matter. What we would do is then add a data row to the table for each up-load file, and then display that grid view with the image preview. The rest of the process is then based on the above grid view. It depends on what kind of up-load control you use. But the above approach would work quite nice, since you add a row to the table for each file up-load, and then display the grid.  And yes, server mappath can be used if you save the up-load file to a folder. It really depends on where file is to be saved.